# US Map with ggplot2

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a map of a categorical variable using ggplot2, where states are shaded one color if they at any point introduced a certain bill, and another color if they never have. The shading appears to work, but the geom objects do not properly fit the state borders ([image: plot output linked here]).

I'm not sure why this is the case. Here's the code I used:

```
all_states <- map_data("state")
all_states <- rename(all_states,
                     state = "region")
all_states$state <- str_to_title(all_states$state)

# select states that introduced bill
int <- read_csv("int.csv", col_types = cols(introduced = col_integer()))
statelist <- int$state 
statelist <- state.name[match(statelist, state.abb)]

int <- cbind(statelist, int)
int <- select(int, statelist, introduced)

int <-  rename(int,
               state = statelist)

stateData <- merge(all_states, int, by="state")

# plot bill introduction
plot1 <- ggplot() + 
geom_polygon(data=stateData, aes(x=long, y=lat, 
  group=group, fill = as.factor(introduced)), color = "grey50") +
   coord_map()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely that the `merge` breaks the order of the maps dataframe given by the `order` column, i.e. `geom_polygon` will connect the points in the order as they appear in the dataset.

Using some fake random example data I can reproduce your issue:

```r
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

all_states <- map_data("state")
all_states <- dplyr::rename(all_states,
                     state = "region"
)
all_states$state <- str_to_title(all_states$state)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

int <- data.frame(
  state = state.name,
  introduced = sample(c(0, 1), 50, replace = TRUE)
)
stateData <- merge(all_states, int, by = "state")

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = stateData, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = as.factor(introduced)), color = "grey50") +
  coord_map()
```

[image]

To fix that we could re-arrange the data by the `order` column (per `state` and `group`)

```r
stateData <- stateData |> 
  arrange(state, group, order)

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = stateData, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = as.factor(introduced)), color = "grey50") +
  coord_map()
```

[image]